# HP Fortify File.Create raises path manipulation vulnerability

Tags: asp.net, security, fortify

I have tried many different approaches `fileInfo`, `filestream` etc.. and cannot get around the vulnerability on the `File.Create(DirName & fileName)` any suggestions or is this just a false positive?

```
DirName=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DirectoryName")
Dim fileName As String = PatientLastName & "_" & PatientFirstName & "_" & CurrentPatEntityID & ".pdf"
For Each c In Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
    If fileName.Contains(c) Then
        fileName = fileName.Replace(c, String.Empty)
    End If
Next

Dim stream As FileStream = File.Create(DirName & fileName)
stream.Write(FinalContents, 0, FinalContents.Length)
stream.Flush()
stream.Close()
stream.Dispose()
```

Comment: Most likely Fortify pointing this out as vulnerability because of fileName variable. I assume that PatientLastName, PatientFirstName contains from user supplied data. That means attacker can spoof this variablis something like ..\..\..\c: which is most common path traversal attack. But it seems that you solved this possibility with for loop. - I dont know VB I just guessing- . If you believe that you solved path traversel and there is no way bypass (like ..%2F..%2fc: URL Encoded form) then it just false positive.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that vulnerability related to Path Traversal attacks.

> A Path Traversal attack aims to access files and directories that are stored outside the web root folder. By browsing the application, the attacker looks for absolute links to files stored on the web server. By manipulating variables that reference files with “dot-dot-slash (../)” sequences and its variations, it may be possible to access arbitrary files and directories stored on file system, including application source code, configuration and critical system files, limited by system operational access control. The attacker uses “../” sequences to move up to root directory, thus permitting navigation through the file system.

This description grabbed from OWASP. ( Further info: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal )

I assume that PatientLastName, PatientFirstName variables under the user ( attacker ) control. Which means we can not trust this variables.

Also let me share some information about GetInvalidFileNameChars functions.

```
 The following characters are invalid in a path: 
Char    Hex Value 
",      0022 
<,      003C 
>,      003E 
|,      007C
```

The for loop looking for these characters because we can not use one of these in file name on Windows OS. But it seems there is no obstacle to use backslash ( \ ).

Let's assume that PatientLastName variable contains "..\ ..\ ..\test" . thus fileName variable is something like "..\ ..\ test_DATA_DATA.pdf" . When you try to create that file with File.Create(DirName & fileName) function. That may lead to create this file at out out directory.

For mitigate you can replace backslash with empty too ( ..%2f..%2f is encoded form of ..\ ..\  ! please, consider this too ) . Fortify can mark this codes as a vulnerable again but this time it will be false positive.

Further info, please read OWASP File System article ( https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_System )